# By using dynamic range COUNTIFS function not working properly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

[image: Sheet3]

Hello All,

Currently working on count SW product which is released by particular publisher. I've attached 2 images for reference. 1St Image shows Column A as SW & Column B as Publisher. 2nd Image shows Column A where Publisher are listed & in Column B I've used COUNTIF formula where I'm matching Sheet1 Column B with Sheet2 Column (i.e publisher match), if that is true then it will provide the count of how many SW product release by particular publisher. In Sheet 2 I've added another column C which shows what exact result is needed by using COUNTIFS formula.
 Below is COUNTIFS formula for reference.

=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A:A,"")

Please let me know where is the problem occurring in this formula?

** More complicated situation where Publisher name is not known, then how we can can add those count?

Comment: This is not a difficult problem but it is quite long, in addition to many other good tools to solve such as query, vba, office365.. you can try from these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the syntax for `COUNTIFS([Range], [Criteria], [2nd Range], [2nd Criteria], etc, etc)`. And the analysis of your formula.

1. First range = `Sheet1!B:B`
2. First criteria = `Sheet2!A:A`
3. 2nd range = `Sheet1!A:A`
4. 2nd criteria = ""

In plain English, count all occurences in Sheet1!B:B where the value is Sheet2!A:A. That alone isn't possible because the criterium must be a value that you wish to count. What you apparently want is this:-

1. First range = `Sheet1!B:B`
2. First criteria = A1
3. 2nd range = `Sheet1!A:A`
4. 2nd criteria = "SW"

In plain English, count all occurrences in Sheet 1 where the publisher (in column B) is the one I entered in `A1` (of the sheet in which the formula resides) and the value in column A is "SW".

In worksheet function syntax:-
`= COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B:B,A1,Sheet1!A:A,"SW")`

This formula can be copied down to make the same search for different publishers in column A (of the sheet where the formula resides).

Comment: I tried your code, thanks it worked. But I have more situation for the same, where Publisher name is not known & we have the SW values in column A (I've attached Image 3). So how to get Count of SW where Publisher is not known?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `COUNIF()` formula like below.

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$12,D2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Post requirements are only unique value for each publisher

Comment: @Harun24HR I've gone the code, but I've added new situation where Publisher is not known, then how can we get the total count of SW for unknown publisher?